# Efficient Product of 3 Sparse Matrices that creates a dense intermediate

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, numerical-methods

I have 3 matrices that are all sparse, `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I need to take the matrix product of `AB`, which results in a dense matrix.
After that, I need the **element wise** product of AB (element wise *) C.
C is sparse, and therefore the element wise multiplication will zero out most of the dense product `AB`, resulting in a sparse matrix again.

Knowing that, I am trying to figure out a strategy for not materializing all of the dense components of AB.

If C_{i,J} is 0, then I should not materialize AB_{i, j}. This means I can skip the dot product of A_{row i} and B_{col j}. But it seems very inefficient to write a for loop over rows of A to pick out the rows I want to materialize.

Could there be another way to intelligently do this multiplication?

Here is an example data generator in R, although the real product AB that I have is more dense than this generator. FWIW help from any programming language would be useful, not necessarily R. (Eigen would be great though!)

```
require(Matrix)

n = 10000
p = 100
A = rsparsematrix(n, p, .1)
B = rsparsematrix(p, p, .1)
C = rsparsematrix(n, p, .1)
```

Comment: I don't see better.  And your "inefficient for loop" saves a considerable amount of time, so seems like a significant net win.

Comment: Not sure why you aren't looping over nonzero entries of C and computing the corresponding dot product of the row of A and the column of B? Too much control overhead in R?

Comment: Right, there is a lot of vectorization that is lost due to for-looping the nonzero entries of C. Also if A and B are stored as sparse matrices with triplet format (nonzero value x stored at location i, j) then I cannot access rows efficiently inside A, or at least I don't know how

Comment: Are you sure `A*B` is dense in your case (usually, the product of two sparse matrices is reasonably sparse)? How are `A`, `B` and `C` actually generated?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty closely related to triangle counting. If A, B, and C were all binary matrices, then you could interpret them as the adjacency matrices for a tripartite graph and count for each edge in C how many triangles it belongs to.

Perhaps there's a triangle-counting community detection in R that could be adapted to your use case.

Underneath such a library is likely the following trick (that I should have a cite for, but don't offhand). It involves sorting the nodes of the graph by degree and directing all of the outgoing edges from low-degree to high. Then for each node, you test each pair of outgoing edges (wedge) for the edge that would complete it.